# How can I act on a taxonomy term in my twig template?

Tags: theming, 8

I'm trying to use two taxonomy items to build a button on my template. The logic is:

```
If this node is exactly equal to taxonomyTermFromVocabularyA
Print a button on the page with a URL built out of taxonomyTermFromVocabularyB
```

I thought I was doing well when a simple test proved that my terms were available. In the template, I tested by adding:

```
<h3>{{ content.field_taxonomy_resource_type }}</h3>
<h3>{{ content.field_taxonomy_topic }}</h3>
```

And out came the expected values on the page:

> Topic Page
>
> Oral Health

However, once I tried to actually use the terms I captured it never worked. The first part of the logic, where the button will eventually be built, I wrote as:

```
{% if content.field_taxonomy_resource_type == "Topic Page" %}
  <p> hello, it's working! </p>
{% endif %}
```

produces no content at all. I expected to see my test paragraph sentence "hello, it's working!" appear on the page.

My best google-foo hasn't helped me at all and, alas, my soul is being crushed. I fear it's something completely obvious that I am just ignorant about.

Can anyone point me to the error of my ways? Why doesn't my twig `if` statement work?

@clive was absolutely right in the suggestion below that I was naming the array and not the particular item I needed when constructing my `if` statement. His correction to my code:

```
{% if node.field_taxonomy_resource_type.entity.label == "Topic Page" %}
```

is not working though, and the best I can tell is that the variable is unavailable to me. When I dump the variable using `{{ dump(node.field_taxonomy_resource_type.entity) }}`, I just get NULL.

Clive's answer worked as soon as I changed out node to paragraph. Thanks!

`{% if paragraph.field_taxonomy_resource_type.entity.label == "Topic Page" %}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`content.field_taxonomy_resource_type` is a render array, which you're comparing against a string. Instead, you need to get access to the label, and extract the term name.

Try this instead (if in a node template):

```
{% if node.field_taxonomy_resource_type.entity.label == "Topic Page" %}
```

Or, as we know it's a paragraph template:

```
{% if paragraph.field_taxonomy_resource_type.entity.label == "Topic Page" %}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. It didn't work:  
{% if content.field_taxonomy_resource_type.entity.name == "Topic Page" %}
    <p> clive's suggestion </p>
{% endif %}
didn't produce anything on the page

Comment: oo, i was using your earlier suggestion. I'll retry it with "label" instead

Comment: Yeah sorry, that's why I commented instead of answering to start with - needed to check

Comment: still doesn't work on my case. {% if content.field_taxonomy_resource_type.entity.label == "Topic Page" %}
    <p> clive's suggestion </p>
{% endif %}  produced nothing on the page. I wonder what I can do to convert an array object to a string that can be compared. Or make my comparison NOT a string? There will only ever be one term from this vocabulary that will be applicable. Can I grab a machine name or an array index or something?

Comment: Strange, that's exactly the method core uses (see core/modules/system/themes/test_theme/node.html.twig for example). Have you tried dumping `content.field_taxonomy_resource_type.entity.label` to see what it contains?

Comment: good suggestion, because dumping that gave me a NULL. I'm assuming the use of "label" here does not mean a label next to a term, right? Because we have removed all labels thematically and it made me pause and wonder. I'm assuming this use of label refers somehow to the taxonomy term itself. A test dump with label removed also produced a NULL.  {{ dump(content.field_taxonomy_resource_type.entity) }}

Comment: but trying to dump just the field with no extension on it broke the page and gave me an empty white screen:  {{ dump(content.field_taxonomy_resource_type) }}  I'm not sure what to make of this and why my variables aren't there.

Comment: No it's (theoretically) the equivalent of the `label()` method on the base Entity class, the same as asking for `node.title.value` or `term.name.value` and so on. Anyway, I'm being an idiot, see the updated answer

Comment: oh damn, {% if node.field_taxonomy_resource_type.entity.label == "Topic Page" %}
    <p> clive's suggestion </p>
{% endif %} did not work. I then tried {{ dump(node.field_taxonomy_resource_type.entity.label) }} and I'll bet you won't be surprised that it's NULL.

Comment: Just going into a meeting, will try to come back to this later - I'd start trying to debug left to right and see where it breaks down, so dump `node`, then `node.field_taxonomy_resource_type` and so on

Comment: ahh... I think that's the key that finally  jogged me into my duh moment. When I dump the {{ dump(node) }} I still get NULL. Duh: I'm doing this on a template that's at the paragraphs level. I should instead do this at the page level.

Comment: thanks for your time up to now. You've been MORE than generous.  Dumping node on page.html.twig produces a blank white screen. I have no idea why I an broken for {{ dump(node) }}. Just to test my own typing, I did dump(user) and at least that worked. I'll try a different template.

Comment: Alright, I don't know if it's just me or if this would happen to anyone. Using {{ dump() }} or {{ dump(node) }} on ANY template breaks the page. It shows up as a blank white screen. This occurred on page.html.twig and on node.html.twig and on my taxonomy template alike. I can't comprehend why there would be no variables at all in my context.

Comment: Got it!  @Clive 's answer except paragraph instead of node:  paragraph.field_taxonomy_resource_type.entity.label

Comment: Sorry @Leraa, somehow missed your last few comments. Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: @Clive what if the site is multilingual? you should use `== "Topic Page"|t %}` to cover for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for something like this as well. I just tested

> {% if node.field_taxonomy_resource_type.entity.label == "Topic Page" %}

and it worked for me after a couple of cache refreshes though - I also got null dumps initially when testing.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try refreshing the cache several times and see if it comes around... What template are you using to test?

Comment: My terminal has about 60 lines of nothing but cache clears from all these tests already. I've also done a few rounds of cache clearing from the admin tool bar too, just to shake things up. I see dumps regularly change according to what test I put in them, so I guess it's working. But I really can't explain my NULLS either

Comment: It's a custom one, using Zurb Foundation, but not the the contrib theme.

Comment: I'm using a node template if that makes a difference.

Comment: here's my code `{% if node.field_tester.entity.label == 'testing' %}
  <h2>{{ label }}</h2>
  {% endif %}`

Comment: I've been looking for this post for hours thanks it works for me. I tried many things {% if node.field_term_reference[0]['#title'] == "bass" %} {% if node.field_term_reference.value == "bass" %} This worked {% if node.field_term_reference.entity.label == "bass" %}

Comment: What if you want to add multiple terms and use AND OR "Topic Page" and "Sub Page". {% if node.field_taxonomy_resource_type.entity.label == "Topic Page" and or "Sub Page" %} How would it be written?